# Mongoose: query one to many relationship, but inverse

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am doing an app with MongoDB/Mongoose/Node.js RESTapi.

I have two models: Books and Authors.

An Author can write many books. Only a book can be written by an author.

The models are defined like this.

**author model**

```
var authorSchema = new Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true},
surname: {type: String, required: true},
```

**book model**

```
var bookSchema = new Schema({
    isbn: {type: String, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    author: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author'},
    description: {type: String}
```

What I am trying to do, is get the books that were written by an author. This is my API endpoint. IdAuthor is the id that mongodb gives.

**on books-routes.js**

```
localhost:3000/api/book/author/:idAuthor

router.get('/author/:idAuthor', (req, res, next) => {

    let idAuthor = req.params.idAuthor;

    Book.find({ author: idAuthor })
        .select('isbn title author description')
        .exec()
        .then(bookCollection => {
            const response = {
                count: bookCollection.length,
                books: bookCollection
            }

            if (response.count) {
                res.status(200).json(bookCollection);
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'This author does not have any book'
                });
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: err
                });
        });
    });
```

Sadly, it is allways returning an empty array of books. I am sure it has something to do about "author" attribute referencing to the authors model.

I have also tried doing this:

```
Book.find({ author: ObjectId(idAuthor) })
```

without luck.

Thank you for your help!